# How can I disable an HTML button based on value stored in PHP array?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a kiosk where people can register for sessions. Each session time slot is displayed in a button with the number of seats remaining. When the capacity reaches 0, text displays under the time slot on the button that says "no seats remaining".

How can i disable the button based on a value in my PHP array, so people are unable to click it?

```
<button type="submit" name="DS1" value="1">
    <h4>10:30 - 11:15</h4>
    <h5><?php if ($result[0]['capacity'] > "0") {
            echo $result[0]['capacity'];
            echo " Seats Remaining";
        } else {
            echo "This Session is Full!";
        } ?></h5>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" name="DS1" value="1" <?php if($result[0]['capacity'] > "0"){echo 'disabled'; } ?>><h4>10:30 - 11:15</h4> <h5><?php if($result[0]['capacity'] > "0"){echo $result[0]['capacity']; echo " Seats Remaining";} else {echo "This Session is Full!";}?></h5></button>
```

Should work, this adds a property [**disabled**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) to the button. It can't be pressed if this property is present

In your case it would be best to make an if-block to make it more readable and easier to adjust:

```
<?php if($result[0]['capacity'] > "0") : ?>
  <button type="submit" name="DS1" value="1">
    <h4>10:30 - 11:15</h4>
    <h5><?php echo($result[0]['capacity']); ?> Seats remaining</h5>
  </button>
<?php else : ?>
  <button type="submit" name="DS1" value="1" disabled>
    <h4>10:30 - 11:15</h4>
    <h5>This Session is Full</h5>
  </button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` checks if the value is 0. If it is it will attach the `disabled` property to the button. Otherwise it will show the non-disabled `button`.

This is more of clean solution I feel anyway.

```
if ($result[0]['capacity'] == "0") {
    <button type="submit" name="DS1" value="1" disabled>Your Button Display Value</button>
} else {
    <button type="submit" name="DS1" value="1">Your Button Display Value</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the button itself inside the seats available, so as to not confuse the user with a button at all. So:

```
<?php
if($result[0]['capacity'] > "0")
{
    $seatsRemaining = $result[0]['capacity'];
    $buttonDisp = "<button type='submit' name='DS1' value='1'><h4>10:30 - 11:15</h4> <h5>$seatsRemaining Seats Remaining</h5></button>";
}
else
{
    $buttonDisp = "This Session is Full!";
}

echo $buttonDisp;
?>
```

Now a user won't see a button to press, and instead see your message.